# Moq - Using MockRepository.Verify() With Times

Tags: moq

I'm looking to see if it's at all possible to specify a Times enum value in the setup of a mocked property that can then be exercised by the MockRepository.Verify() method at the Assert block of my AAA-style test. My current code reads like so:

```
        // Arrange
        var repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);

        var mockLogin = repository.Create<Login>();
        mockLogin.SetupProperty(d => d.LoginID, 1515254);

        var mockIApplicationEventLogService = repository.Create<IApplicationEventLogService>();
        mockIApplicationEventLogService.Setup(d => d.InsertApplicationEventLog(It.IsAny<ApplicationEventLog>())).Verifiable();

        var mockILoginResetFailedService = repository.Create<ILoginResetFailedService>();
        mockILoginResetFailedService.Setup(d => d.GetLoginResetFailedByLoginID(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((LoginResetFailed)null);

        var mockApplicationEventLog = repository.Create<ApplicationEventLog>();
        mockApplicationEventLog.SetupAllProperties();

        var LoginWorkflowService = new LoginWorkflowService()
        {
            ApplicationEventLogService = mockIApplicationEventLogService.Object,
            ApplicationEventLog = mockApplicationEventLog.Object,
            LoginResetFailedService = mockILoginResetFailedService.Object
        };

        // Act 
        var result = LoginWorkflowService.CheckLoginResetFailuresLock(mockLogin.Object, It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<SecurityPolicy_Aggregate>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>());

        // Assert
        result.Should().BeTrue();
        mockIApplicationEventLogService.Verify(d => d.InsertApplicationEventLog(It.IsAny<ApplicationEventLog>()), Times.Never);
```

What I'd like to be able to do is call repository.Verify() at the end, but with my current code the Verify() call will expect InsertApplicationEventLog to have been called when in fact I expect it to never have been called. I have tried passing Times.Never into the Setup method for mockIApplicationEventLogService but it doesn't seem that there's a method override that takes it. Am I limited to individual Verify() calls if I have mocks in my repository that should never be called, or is there a way around this?

Comment: At present there is no way around this as it is a limitation of the framework in it current state. You could consider opening an [issue request](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues) on the project's site to see if the developer can advise on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as Nkosi said, it's not currently possible to do this. There is a request for this at the following URL:

https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/373